# Infopath Filler Crashes When Using Person Picker

Tags: infopath

I am using InfoPath 2013 and have created a test form with only one field, a person/group picker. If I configure SharePoint to open the from in the browser everything works correctly, but if I switch it to use InfoPath Filler the form will open but any attempt to look up a username by clicking the picker button will cause InfoPath to stop working (crash). The system error log has nothing useful and no other messages are displayed.

Searching on the internet doesn't turn up much beyond some tutorials about setting the default value to the current user. Has anyone ever had a problem like this? I am not a farm admin so I can't change settings at that level. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I spent days to fix the same issue, finally I did fix following the blog [Fixing the AppFabric Cache cluster](http://web.archive.org/web/20130817013314/http://mmman.itgroove.net/2013/07/fixing-the-appfabric-cache-cluster-in-sharepoint-2013/)

I know it's not advised here to put links for solutions, But there are a lots of solutions to fix AppFabric Cache cluster issues.

Comment: Typically no, we prefer more detailed answers from the referring link, the link is very detailed and would be hard to pull out so I linked to a more permanent link to the blog post.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the permanent link. The link helped me to fix the InfoPath crash when people picker control selected. and “Sorry, we’re having trouble reaching the server.” issue on list form people picker.